# How to retain the decimal format when using sum function

Tags: xslt

I need to add each occurrence of totalPackageQuantity, totalGrossVolume and totalGrossWeight

```
<packageTotal>
  <packageTypeCode>BX</packageTypeCode>
  <totalPackageQuantity>3</totalPackageQuantity>
  <totalGrossVolume measurementUnitCode="CBM">0.026000</totalGrossVolume>
  <totalGrossWeight measurementUnitCode="KGM">2.880000</totalGrossWeight>
</packageTotal>
  <packageTotal>
  <packageTypeCode>BX</packageTypeCode>
  <totalPackageQuantity>3</totalPackageQuantity>
  <totalGrossVolume measurementUnitCode="CBM">0.026000</totalGrossVolume>
  <totalGrossWeight measurementUnitCode="KGM">2.880000</totalGrossWeight>
</packageTotal>
```

On the above xml structure my expected value for each

5.760000 (for totalGrossWeight)

0.052000 (for totalGrossVolume)

I'm currently using this

```
sum(packageTotal/totalGrossWeight)
```

using the sum function it strips some decimal value, I need the decimal format to be as is. And if there is only single occurrence the value will be as is.

Comment: Not sure what your question is. The result of `sum()` is, of course, a number. Use the `format-number()` function to format the number any way you need it.

Comment: @michael.hor257k sorry if I confused you I rephrased it hope it's clear now. Thanks.

Comment: I don't see anything new. Do you know the required precision in advance, or can it change from case to case?

Comment: @michael.hor257k Based on the files that I have right now it will have six decimal places. But is it possible to retain the decimal places as is?

Comment: Is this question not answered?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to "retain" the format, because the given values must be converted to number before they can be summed - and a number does not have a format.

If you know the required precision is six decimal places, then use simply:

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(packageTotal/totalGrossWeight), '0.000000')"/>
```

If you need to *restore* the original format dynamically, try:

```
<xsl:variable name="format" select="translate(packageTotal[1]/totalGrossWeight, '123456789', '000000000')" />
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(packageTotal/totalGrossWeight), $format)"/>
```